# Is there a VFR mobile app that shows other aircraft in real time?

Tags: safety, visual-flight-rules, radar

In the UK, are there any apps available that show a real time radar / GPS of other aircraft and ideally their callsign?

As I fly Microlights, I only fly VFR, but in a high wing and often with low cloud, it's too easy not to spot others and would be much easier / safer if there was an app that handled this.

Comment: This is like my absolute sweet spot of question :) I could chat for hours about VFR tech! Give me a shout if you want to know more.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the great answer, will investigate them and decide on one! I like that SkyEcho horizon and PFD that makes it look like you're flying a 737 ;)

Comment: I wonder: Do you want to look at such app while flying VFR? For what purpose exactly? I think such app may be useful outside of planes or for passengers, but not for pilots during flight, except maybe if you have an instrument failure. However think: Where do such apps get their data? Via mobile internet, most likely. Will it be available during the whole flight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most commonly used moving map GPS app in the UK for VFR flight is [SkyDemon](https://www.skydemon.aero/) which is an absolutely incredible application written by what I consider to be geniuses. You really cannot get better. A close second is probably [RunwayHD](https://www.airboxaero.com/).

If you pair either of these apps with an electronic conspicuity device such as [Rosetta Pilotaware](https://www.pilotaware.com/rosetta) or [SkyEcho](https://uavionix.com/products/skyecho/), then your moving map shows *some* (but crucially not *all*) other air traffic. Sometimes this is because of the differing technology, other times its due to capability of the device, and then there is interference between the big metal box you're in and the receiving/transmitting antennae.

Functionality varies between pilotaware and skyecho, and it's a bit of a VHS vs Betamax fight right now. You can hedge your bets on one, or wait until the fight is won. But neither device will ever be a complete replacement for the Mk1 eyeball. Traffic separation will *always* be your responsibility as PIC of a VFR aircraft.

It's also worth mentioning that the CAA is still doing a rebate scheme on EC devices as they have stated that they would like all aircraft to be carrying one. https://www.caa.co.uk/general-aviation/aircraft-ownership-and-maintenance/electronic-conspicuity-devices/

Comment: I like SkyDemon, it's a really well designed app. I'm of two minds whether to plug traffic data into it though. Technology is already causing too much head-down in the cockpit, I'd rather pilots were looking out than getting fixated on screens.

Comment: @GdD aha - thats where bluetooth equipped headsets come in. It _talks_ to me to tell me where to point my Mk1 eyeballs. But saying that you're of course 100% right. Eyes outside not in the cockpit

Comment: What does Mk1 mean?

Comment: @Someone https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Mk1%20eyeball

Answer (score 6):

The free [SafeSky app](https://www.safesky.app/) does exactly this. It's very popular in France (where it's from) and is gaining traction in other countries as well.

[image]

It shows data from other SafeSky users but also from all other traffic information sources (ADS-B, FLARM, MODE-S...) that are picked up by ground stations.

Of course it can't be 100% accurate and requires at least an EDGE cellular connection. So it's still your responsibility as PIC to be on the lookout.

---

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with SkySafe. I just think it's awesome

Comment: I've been keeping an eye on this, it is indeed getting some traction. From experience, I get a pretty good cell signal at 2000ft, but much higher I get nothing.

Comment: Ultimately, those tools are mostly useful when around airfields or at low altitude, when traffic is dense. When cruising, PIC's eyes with the assistance of Flight Information / Flight Following works best!

Comment: They certainly are useful around airfields, but in certain areas enroute (a number of which I could name off the bat) an extra pair of digital eyes is absolutely beneficial.

Comment: The high end Sentry receiver includes a FLARM chip, so no internet required.

Comment: It should be mentioned that supposedly you should not use cell-phones when flying. They are said to create problems for the cell phone network when one phone connects to several base stations normally out of sight. Other possible problems is when you receive a call on short final (happened to me) or when you place it next to the magnetic compass (been there as well).

Comment: @ghellquist don't worry, the carrier network will be just fine. For the call issue, one can always enable "Do not disturb" mode and be done with it. And for the compass, just put it far enough as you would do with any metallic/magnetic/electronic object that you may have to put somewhere on the dashboard. But this is a good point. One has to make sure the compass is OK before taking off!

Comment: @Jamiec are there any devices that allow mobile signal to work above 2k ft? Some kind of mobile satellite internet device or something?

Comment: @Cloud not that I know of

Comment: @cloud that could be a great question to ask so the technicalities of why it doesn't work can be answered.

Answer (score 3):

Captain obvious here! Whichever app you choose to use, it absolutely does not diminish the necessity to scan the surroundings and monitor radio(s) **at all**, and it should not completely remove the anxiety about other traffic and all things flying in general.

As stated in the other answers, none of the apps can provide 100% coverage of other traffic, and as such may provide false sense of security.

Should you choose to use one (and I recommend you should, despite this "rant"), make sure you learn and use proper scanning technique, maintaining your main focus on the surroundings of the aircraft, not the inside.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Android device with gps, or an external gps, Avare provides a glass cockpit type moving map experience. If you add a pair of rtl sdr it will also plot other planes with ADS Mode C and I'm pretty sure Mode S. I haven't looked lately to see if it has added support for TCAS. The thing you wont get without internet is plane type descriptions since that is provided from database lookups of the tail number sent as part of the ads message.

You can download all of the charts you need (at least in the US) and fly without needing internet.

The ideal setup is a battery pack with a USB-C hub and PD for your device that has USB-A ports for the rtl devices. That way it can be stand alone from the aircraft electronics.